# NSNotification alert body issue

Tags: ios

i want to print in notification body like today is jane's birthday

for that i am using logic like below

```
notification.alertBody = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Today is %@'s Birthday",  [_combinedNameArray objectAtIndex:i]];
```

but in notification it only shows the name which is jane and not showing Today is birthday

plz tell me what i am doing wrong ?

thank you

Comment: you this code looks perfect.

Comment: Can you show more codes

Comment: after this Today is %@\'s Birthday it is working perfectly :) yes its working but do you think  still there is something wrong im doing if yes then plz suggest :)

Comment: I dont see why ' has to be follwed by \. I can nslog the same string without \

Comment: it wasn't getting displayed in alertbody but when i used \ then it started to show today is jane's birthday i dont know why. spread some light over this Anoop ji :)

Comment: As in Nirav's answer you saw rmaddy commenting same thing. Can u try once in a new project, only with `NSLog(@"%@",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Today is %@'s Birthday",  @"anoop"]);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
notification.alertBody = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Today is %@\'s Birthday",  [_combinedNameArray objectAtIndex:i]];
```

(' character needs an escape character)

Comment: Why does the apostrophe need to be escaped?

Comment: glad to help. It happens with everyone :-)